# How to mix embedded code blocks with data-binding expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I read this document http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112
where explains all the **embedded code blocks** available but I want to combine two of them.

I want to use base **<% ... %>** embedded code blocks with **<%# ... %>** data-binding expression

Example I want to add an "If" condition to this code:

`<asp:Label ID="lblHello" runat="server" Text="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "[\"Txt\"]")%>"></asp:Label>`

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference in the `<%` and `<%#` is mainly in *when* they're run (the former at render time, the latter at data binding). As such, it makes no sense to "combine" them.

What you *likely* want to do, is to run some additional code when data binding to do your `if` statement. If it's a simple expression, you can just inline it:

`<%# MyProperty ? Eval("Txt") : Eval("OtherTxt") %>`

If it's more complicated, then it's usually best to just call a code-behind method to do it for you:

`<%# MyMethod(Eval("Txt")) %>`